Owin authentication to two different areas
I have searched for this, but everything seems to refer to different levels of authorisation. We have an ASP.NET MVC app with top level controllers and views (open to all who surf), followed by two areas - Homeowners and Vendors - each one with totally different navbars and functions.
In Startup.Auth.vb, ConfigureAuth redirects to the homeowner login page. The same controller (LoginOutController) is used for both login views.
 Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
 Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
 Imports Microsoft.Owin
 Imports Owin
 Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies

 Partial Public Class Startup

Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)

    app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
       .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
       .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
           .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
               validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(19),
               regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
       .LoginPath = New PathString("/LoginOut/Login")
    })
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie)

End Sub

End Class

The main Navbar had two login links, one for homeowners - Homeowners/Manage/Landing - and for vendors - Vendors/VendorsManage/VendorsLanding - where homeowners and vendors are areas.
Of course, if the user clicks on the Vendors link they are still going to be directed to the homeowners login view - sooo, how do I fix this so that I can redirect to the correct login view?
EDIT
Basically, what I am trying to achieve is if a user, either by clicking a login button or from a saved URL, will be directed to LoginOut/Login if the link is Homeowners/* and LoginOut/VendorLogin is the link is Vendors/* - Homeowners and Vendors are two separate areas.
UPDATE Most of the way there now - can login to separate areas by creating a class like this
Public Class AreaAuthorise
Inherits AuthorizeAttribute
Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
    Dim controller As String = filterContext.RouteData.Values("controller").ToString()
    filterContext.Result = New RedirectToRouteResult(New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.controller = "../LoginOut", .action = "/VendorLogin"}))
End Sub

End Class
Then replacing the <Authorize> at the top of the control with <AreaAuthorise>
The remaining problem is incorporating the ReturnUrl - if someone could suggest something I would be very grateful.
